# Display Table in "Show" Page using the same related ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I wanted to show the others related Items of a same thing when finishing adding something.

I have a normal crud scaffold, so when I add a "Task" which is related to a project, I wanted to when it redirect to "Show" to a table be formed showing other "tasks" of the same related project...

show.html.erb

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>Seq</th>
  <th>Descr</th>
  <th>Seqpai</th>
  <th>Type</th>
  <th>Hour</th>
  <th>Pid</th>
  <th colspan="3"></th>
  </tr>
  </thead>

 <tbody>
 <% @lookup.each do |lookup| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= task.seq %></td>
    <td><%= task.descr %></td>
    <td><%= task.seqpai %></td>
    <td><%= task.typo %></td>
    <td><%= task.hour %></td>
    <td><%= task.projeto.name %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</tbody>
```

tasks controller =>

```
def lookup
@taskete = Task.where(@projeto_id)
end
```

Tasks Belong to Projeto and Projeto has many Tasks

Comment: Sorry, the best is to question How, How do i put this Loop to show a specified "Project Tasks" selected by the user? THe user select "Project #1" and then in a table-like it shows all the tasks "Project #1" has.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what's the problem. But if the source code of your controller you define variable called "@taskete", then in the view you are iterating over "@lookup".

Your loop in view should be: @taskete.each do |task|

Answer (score 0):

Tasks belong to projecto and projecto has many tasks.  So to show all the tasks of the projecto of the current task do...

```
 <% @taskete.projecto.tasks.each do |task| %>
```

If you only want to show the other tasks (i.e. don't show the current task in the list, only the related tasks) you may want to do...

```
 <% @taskete.projecto.tasks.each do |task| %>
   <% next if @taskete == task %>
```

...which will skip the current loop if the task in the collection is @tasketo